# Ajax request not being sent from JQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the following code for sending ajax request but the request is not  being sent. Can anyone help me to find the problem?

```
 $("input.ub").click(function () {
     console.log("I am here");
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
     var pid = "p" + id.substring(1, 2);
     var text = $("#" + pid).text();
     $("#" + pid).html('<input type="text" id="up" value="' + text + '" /><input type="button" id="req" value="Submit" />');

     //Ajax request to be sent
     $("#req").one("click", function () {

         //var action = $("#postform").attr('action');
         console.log("I am Second");
         var form_data1 = {
             post: $("#up").val(),
             is_ajax: 1,
             update: parseInt(id.substring(1, 2))
         };
         console.log($("#up").val());
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "updatePosts.php",
             data: form_data1,
             success: function (response) {
                 if (response == "success") {
                     console.log("Succes MEssage");
                     $(location).attr('href', 'viewPosts.php');
                 } else console.log("You are failed here instead");
             }
         });
         console.log("Request not sent");
         return false;
     });
```

I am getting the failure console messages. But i don't see any problem in the code.

Comment: Please post the console errors.

Comment: You need to put the error in the `error:` event and not outside the call. You will see that error message "Request not sent" each time even when successful. And console.log the response before testing it to see what is returned from the server if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning "request not sent" even when it is successful. You need to use the `error` setting in your AJAX call.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have forgotten a bracket after else...

```
           $("input.ub").click(function(){
            console.log("I am here");
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var pid="p"+id.substring(1,2);
            var text=$("#"+pid).text();
            $("#"+pid).html('<input type="text" id="up" value="'+text+'" /><input type="button" id="req" value="Submit" />');
            //Ajax request to be sent
            $("#req").one("click",function(){

    //var action = $("#postform").attr('action');
                console.log("I am Second");
    var form_data1 = {
        post: $("#up").val(),
        is_ajax: 1,
                        update:parseInt(id.substring(1,2))
    };  
                console.log($("#up").val());
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatePosts.php",
        data: form_data1,
        success: function(response){
            if(response == "success"){ 
                console.log("Succes MEssage");
                $(location).attr('href','viewPosts.php');
            }
            else { <=====HERE
                console.log("You are failed here instead");
            }
    });
    console.log("Request not sent");
    return false;
});
```